# How to get google reCaptcha image source using Selenium Webdrive?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I understood that reCaptcha loads a new frame document into 
pages iframe. 
To fetch captcha's source image I need to switch frames in selenium webdriver, and iterate the loaded frame for image src.

This is the iframe i want to switch to -

> 

However, google uses random name attribute for each frame, and switching frame by xpath throws "an unable to locate element" error.

`browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/iframe'))`

Using

```
> driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
```

Fails to locate iframe.

**Bottom line, How to switch to another frame using Selenium webdriver?**

Comment: please share the html and its is advisable to use relative xpath in place of absolute xpath

Comment: I have used relative xpath in the example, It does not find the iframe because google loads a new recaptcha frame (iframe) which loads new document so in the new document the iframe will not be existed.